# Is this sentence with no actor or subject in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I don't see any actor or subject in the following sentence

> North Carolina Is Ordered to Redraw Its Gerrymandered Congressional Map.

Am I correct and is this sentence in the passive voice?

Comment: A newspaper headline would read, *"North Carolina **Ordered** to Redraw Gerrymandered Congressional Map"*.  Your example seems like neither a regular sentence nor a headline.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes

Yes, this is in **the** passive voice. An agent could be indicated while remainign in the passive with:

> North Carolina Is Ordered to Redraw Its Gerrymandered Congressional Map by Federal Court

or it coulf be recast in the active voice with:

> Federal Court orders North Carolina to Redraw Its Gerrymandered Congressional Map.

Without the "by" clause, the passive voice serves to hide the agent.